# Unable to resize imageview after applying ratio to the image sdWebImage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am having trouble with loading from url resized to custom ratio image through sdwebimage and resizing my imageview. I have tried many options with the imageview content mode, but none has work. My table view is resizable and has estimated row 300 and I have applied automaticDimension (and even has applied (tableView.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight). If you could give great example in code, that would be very helpful.

Thank you very much in advance.

My tableview code is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor? = UIColor.blue
    tableView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    tableView.register(OffersTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.backgroundColor? = UIColor.blue
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return welcomePages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) as! OffersTVCell
    cell.backgroundColor? = .red

    let pages = welcomePages[indexPath.row]
    let size = (Constants.screenWidth * 0.88)
    cell.offerImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: pages.pageImage), placeholderImage: nil) { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cacheType:SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: URL?) in
        guard let cellImage = image else { return }
        let image = self.resizeImage(image: cellImage, newWidth: size)
        cell.offerImageView.image = image

    }

    return cell
}

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

and my tableview cell code is:

```
class OffersTVCell: UITableViewCell, SDWebImageManagerDelegate {

let offerImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return iv
}()



override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let imageSize = (Constants.screenWidth * 0.88)
    contentView.addSubview(offerImageView)

    offerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true

    offerImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    offerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize).isActive = true
    offerImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    layoutIfNeeded()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

the rows appear like that:

[image]